# unable to return an Array from a class

Tags: arrays, scala, types

Trying to understand 'apply' method. I want to create a class which returns either a List, Array or a Set depending on the argument passed. The code works for List and Set but not for Array. I am not able to understand the issue

```
class CollectionFactory [A](s:String){}
    object CollectionFactory {
       def apply[A](s: String): Traversable[A] = {
           s match {
              case "list" => {
                  List[A]()
              }
//this doesnt work. It seems using [A] is incorrect. How do I specify the type?
      /*
      case "array" => {
        new Array[A](1)
      }
    */
          case _ => {
             Set[A]()      }
          }
      }
    }

val c = CollectionFactory[Int]("list")
c: Traversable[Int] = List()

CollectionFactory[String]("list")
res0: Traversable[String] = List()

CollectionFactory[Boolean]("")
res1: Traversable[Boolean] = Set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `ClassTag[A]` to instantiate a new `Array[A]`. This is easy to fix by adding an `implicit ct: ClassTag[A]` parameter.

```
object CollectionFactory {
  def apply[A: reflect.ClassTag](s: String): Traversable[A] = {
    s match {
      case "list" => List[A]()
      case "array" => new Array[A](1)
      case _ => Set[A]()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: #1 isn't a problem: it will get implicitly converted to `WrappedArray`, which _is_ a `Traversable`